# How to remove prefix in jquery id

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, serialization, array.prototype.map

How to remove prefix in jquery .?

```
<td><span id="stu1" class="reject-student ">Not Selected</span></td>
<td><span id="stu2" class="select-student ">Selected</span></td>
<td><span id="stu5" class="select-student ">Selected</span></td>
```

jquery:

```
var selected = $(".select-student").map(function() {
return this.id; 
}).get();
```

i have trid like this:

```
var selected = $(".select-student").map(function() {
var id = $('span[id^="stu"]').remove();
return this.id; 
}).get();
```

I am getting result like stu1 stu2 i want to send only 1 and 2.. how can i do that.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need `$('span[id^="stu"]').remove();` the statement with remove element.

A simple solution is to use the [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method  to replace *stu*

```
var selected = $(".select-student").map(function() {
   return this.id.replace('stu', ''); 
}).get();
```

Additionally, you can also use RegEx to remove all non numeric characters

```
var selected = $(".select-student").map(function() {
   return this.id.replace (/[^\d]/g, ''); 
}).get();
```